# What's wrong with this SQL statement? Select and delete in same transaction

Tags: mysql

I get a syntax error on this statement. Any idea why?

My only guess is that maybe the session record has been locked from the select, and therefore cannot be deleted in the same transaction. But that doesn't seem like it would cause a syntax error.

```
insert into sessions_history 
      select * 
      from sessions 
      where session_id = 'jjmn6hmuor8mqa2j1vb4gdpno0'; 

delete from sessions 
     where session_id = 'jjmn6hmuor8mqa2j1vb4gdpno0';
```

and here's the error:

Error Number: 1064

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete from sessions where session_id = 'vk744qiebkfr0el7tesi65us04'' at line 1

insert into sessions_history select * from sessions where session_id = 'vk744qiebkfr0el7tesi65us04'; delete from sessions where session_id = 'vk744qiebkfr0el7tesi65us04';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error are you actually getting?

Comment: can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: Do you have the same schema for both tables?

Comment: Do you have MySQL in multi statement mode? Also you really should name the columns you're inserting into/selecting from.

Comment: There actually was a column out of order somehow, thanks for randomly finding a different issue for me. But the whole thing works when I separate the statements, so it must have to do with having them in a single transaction. I'll check on the multi-statement mode, but I swear I've done them before ont eh same server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have parenthesis in an insert into ... select .. statement.

```
insert into sessions_history 
      select * 
      from sessions 
      where session_id = 'jjmn6hmuor8mqa2j1vb4gdpno0';
```

Comment: Sorry, I added those in an attempt to fix it. Same without.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with these 2 queries as you show in your last edit. Perhaps you're issuing them through some API in some programming language rather, most of which doesn't allow you to issue multiple queries through one API call.